# I cannot use ML5 (unpkg) in a Chrome extension project

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, unpkg

Good evening

I am completely new in the field of browser extensions, so this might seem trivial to some, however....

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use an 'unpkg' in a chrome extension. I have been dabbling with Content Security Policy (CSP), but I just cannot figure out how to make it work. I am using manifest version 3, which might even be incompatible, but I don't know if switching to manifest version 2 will even be the solution as a lot of other problems and questions then start to crop up.

I have tried to use sandbox mode, but I have no idea how to test it, so I presume I did not set it up correctly.

In the examples below I have also tried to add CSP in the HTML head in a `<meta>` tag, but I do not think that works.

This is the primary error:
[image]

I have tried copy/pasting the contents of the unpkg link (https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js) into a new file, which yields:
[image]

No matter what I do to my content-security-policy in the manifest.json this is always the result.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Getting Started Example",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"version": "2.1",
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"permissions": ["storage"],
"content-security-policy": { 
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://unpkg.com/*"
},
"action": {
    "default_popup": "main.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
}
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sentiment analysis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Resources/css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ml5.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The rest of the project is in this repo.

I am not a skilled programmer at all, so all of this is most definitely amateurish. All I need is to get this working, not make it safe nor beautiful (that may come later.. :D ).

For the record, I have all of it working in a local javascript file, it is this CSP thing that is bugging me..

[This is the local Github repo](https://github.com/yoyohohoxd/prototype3.git), **but please be aware of some NSFW language**, as what I am trying to do is reverse negative sentences on the internet.. Most in the main.html.

NEW MANIFEST:

```
    {
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "2.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage"],
    "content-security-policy": { 
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'  'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'  'unsafe-eval'",
        "sandbox": "allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://unpkg.com/*"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "main.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
            "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
            "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
            "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using CDN? You can bypass this error by downloading and saving the ML5 library in the extension source code directory, then loading it from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not sure what you mean by CDN? Can you tell me exactly what you mean by downloading the source code directory, and how do I then load it? :)

Comment: Save this file [https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js](https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js) as `ml5.min.js` in the same directory as manifest.json. Then, in the html file, change the reference to `<script src="ml5.min.js">`

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get home later. Thank you so much @Neea :))

Comment: @Neea Unfortunately, that did not fix it.. Your solution yielded the 'Uncaught EvalError:' error in the second screenshot as well as the 'DevTools failed to load source map:' also in the second screenshot. :(

Comment: ah ok, I see, the script is calling eval (very unsafe). In the manifest  "content-security-policy" "extension_pages" would need to add 'unsafe-eval'. Please also see this page to understand what this means: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/sandboxingEval/

Comment: @Neea Again, thank you for helping. Unfortunately it still didn't help. I read the page you linked to, but I stil don't get it. Nothing seems to happen at all when I alter the content-security-policy. Do you think there is anything I can do, or is it simply not possible? EDIT: I have edited the original post where I have added the updated manifest.json at the bottom

Comment: I have reproduced the issue, I get it now. in manifest "content-security-policy" is misspelled so it does nothing; should be "content_security_policy". MV3 does not allow unsafe-eval (this will be the message after fixing the manifest). This leaves options: (1) downgrade to MV2 or (2) find alternative that does not call eval, (3) try to hack it somehow, maybe in content script or fork the lib.

Comment: @Neea Oh. My. God. You did it! Thank you so much! I downgraded to version 2 and after debugging a little I made it work. I can't believe it.. :D :D

Comment: Glad it worked : )